# Creating Fragments from List with tabs

Tags: javascript, android-listview, android-fragmentactivity

After way to long of a time between learning to code and now, I am trying to create an Android app that is using a card list view and use tabs.

I want to be able to have the cards list in all 3 tabs but a different list in each.Right now with what I have done, I get the same set in all 3 tabs. I know I am doing something wrong but after reading on Fragments and tabs, I cannot figure out how to implement this.

I have the following in my MainActivity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Card.CardMenuListener<Card>{

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    private Drawable oldBackground = null;
    private int currentColor = 0xFF3F9FE0;


       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // This is quick way of theming the action bar without using styles.xml (e.g. using ActionBar Style Generator)
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark)));
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

                    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Initializes a CardAdapter with a blue accent color and basic popup menu for each card
            CardAdapter<Card> cardsAdapter = new CardAdapter<Card>(this)
                    .setAccentColorRes(android.R.color.holo_blue_light)
                    .setPopupMenu(R.menu.card_popup, this);

            cardsAdapter.add(new CardHeader(this, R.string.themeheader));
            cardsAdapter.add(new Card("Action", "Launcher")
                            .setThumbnail(this, R.drawable.apps_actionlauncherpro));  // sets a thumbnail image from drawable resources
            cardsAdapter.add(new Card("ADW", "Launcher")
                                    .setThumbnail(this, R.drawable.apps_adwex));  // sets a thumbnail image from drawable resources
            cardsAdapter.add(new Card("Apex", "Launcher")
                                    .setThumbnail(this, R.drawable.apps_apexlauncher));  // sets a thumbnail image from drawable resources
            cardsAdapter.add(new Card("Nova", "Launcher")
                                    .setThumbnail(this, R.drawable.apps_novalauncher));  // sets a thumbnail image from drawable resources

            CardListView cardsList = (CardListView) findViewById(R.id.cardsList);
            cardsList.setAdapter(cardsAdapter);

                    final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
                                    .getDisplayMetrics());
                    pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

                    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        }


        @Override
        public void onMenuItemClick(Card card, MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(this, card.getTitle() + ": " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I have this to set the tabs to provide the 3 that I want

```
    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            private final int[] TITLES = { R.string.tab1, R.string.tab2, R.string.tab3 };

            public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                            return getString(R.string.tab1).toUpperCase(l);
                    case 1:
                            return getString(R.string.tab2).toUpperCase(l);
                    case 2:
                            return getString(R.string.tab3).toUpperCase(l);
                    }
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    Fragment f = new Fragment();
                    switch(position){
                    case 0:
                            f=ThemeCardFragment.newInstance(position);     
                            break;
                    case 1:
                            f=ThemeCardFragment.newInstance(position);     
                            break;
                    }
                    return f;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                    return TITLES.length;
            }
```

I placed the following in my Fragment which I am sure is wrong.

```
    public class ThemeCardFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

private int position;

public static ThemeCardFragment newInstance(int position) {
    ThemeCardFragment f = new ThemeCardFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    fl.setLayoutParams(params);

    return fl;
}
    }
```

I have tried to look at examples on here, tutorials and the Android dev but I am missing something that would allow me to do this.

Realistically I would like to define the

```
    ("Action", "Launcher")
```

in the CardsAdapter as strings from my Strings.xml

Any insight to pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated. I seem to keep heading in wrong directions and have spent at least 10 hours trying to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: I assume this should have been tagged "java", not "javascript".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making separate fragments for separate content.

Inflate the layouts from the `onCreateView()` method in the fragments and initialize your listviews from there. Remove the listview code from your MainActivity and put it inside your fragments.

As for your ViewPager, change it to something like this:

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Fragment f = new Fragment();
                switch(position){
                case 0:
                        f= new FragmentTheme();     
                        break;
                case 1:
                        f= new FragmentExtras();     
                        break;
                case 2:
                        f= new FragmentContact();     
                        break;
                }
                return f;
        }
```

Hope this helps. I have modified your github repo to reflect on these changes.

Make sure to accept this as the answer if it solved your problem.